# if stmt with NoRows or Int? sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm clueless about the best way to go about this. The current query is fine. The problem is i want the if statement to be true if no row is returned. I also dont want to write the query twice so how do i write this in a way that the if statement is true and runs?

```
IF (select AnInt from ATable where Cond) = expectedInt
begin ... end
```

Comment: Is your subquery guaranteed to return no more than 1 row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `NULL` `AnInt` is not possible then you could make the null sub-select result on no-match equal to `expectedInt`

```
IF isnull((select AnInt from ATable where Cond), expectedInt) = expectedInt
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so?

```
DECLARE @Test INT

SELECT @Test = AnInt
FROM ATable
WHERE Cond

IF @Test IS NULL OR @Test = expectedInt
BEGIN
...
END
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think bummi's answer is more efficient than mine

Answer (score 2):

```
IF Coalesce((select TOP 1 AnInt from ATable where Cond),expectedInt) = expectedInt
begin
end
```

Comment: +1 Best to Use isnull though as coalesce will execute the query twice.